# Modifying vectors of generic types

Tags: generics, rust

I have a function that takes as input a vector of a particular type (generic). I'd like to, if a given type has a property, create a modified version with a changed property and write it to output buffer. If the type is irrelevant to the use case, just skip this step. So, along the lines of

```
use std::io;

pub fn write_obj_to_buf<T>(
    obj_vec: &Vec<T>,
    output: &mut dyn io::Write,
) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {

    // new_vec = empty vector
    // for each element in obj_vec
    // if T=something specific -> append to new_vec modified version (how to modify?), else append existing
    
    unsafe {
        let buf_view: &[u8] = slice::from_raw_parts(
            new_vec.as_ptr() as *const u8,
            new_vec.len() * mem::size_of::<T>(),
        );
        output.write_all(buf_view)?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

What is the idiomatic way to do this in Rust? I'm new to generics, not sure if `std::any::Any` is of relevance here?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way in this case is describe all of your types set and implementing trait for it. If you are don't need to do for a some types, just still empty implementation. See example:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn foo(&self) -> ();
}

struct Foo;
struct Bar;

impl MyTrait for Foo {
    fn foo(&self) -> () {
        println!("Hello from Foo");
    }
}

impl MyTrait for Bar {
    fn foo(&self) -> () {
        //println!("Hello from Bar");
    }
}

fn f(v: &Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>>) -> () {
    v.iter().for_each(|item| item.foo());
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = vec![Box::new(Foo), Box::new(Bar)];
    f(&v);
}

// output: Hello from Foo
```

Another way is creating `enum MyEnum` with all your types inside and implementing it's behaviour. Such as:

```
enum MyEnum {
    Foo(u32),
    Bar(String),
}

impl MyEnum {
    pub fn foo_here(&self) -> () {
        match self {
            MyEnum::Foo(_) => println!("Hello from Foo"),
            MyEnum::Bar(_) => (),
        }
    }
}

fn f(v: &Vec<MyEnum>) -> () {
    v.iter().for_each(|item| item.foo_here());
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<MyEnum> = vec![MyEnum::Foo(2), MyEnum::Bar("".into())];
    f(&v);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The enum way seems very elegant indeed!